# Java throw e becomes null on Android

Tags: java, android

I have the following:

```
     try {
        response.statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();    
     } catch(IOException e) {
        throw e;
     }
```

I look at the debugger and `e = UnknownHostException`

After the throw I have:

```
    try {
        NetworkResponse response = NetworkHelper.getByURL(url);
     } catch(Exception e) {   <------- IT LANDS HERE, BUT e=null
        ExceptionHelper.announce(e);        
        throw e;
    }
```

So after the throw my catch block gets the exception but it's null. 
The debugger shows e=null.

I have no idea why this would happen.

Comment: Can you show the call hierarchy?

Comment: Is it still null after you step to the next line?

Comment: try e.printStackTrace() and see if it prints, then try e.getMessage() and see if getMessage() is null. If it is (which I think), it's because your throwing a Exception (top level) and not a specific exception.

Comment: Unsolicited :). It may be worthwhile to rethrow a more layer-savvy exception by wrapping the cause, like, throw new MyHigherLevelException("Network response problem", e);

Comment: To exclude every doubt, you are sure it is not that `e.toString()` returned `null`? Of course `throw new IOException(e);` would be possible too.

Comment: I added throw new Exception(e) and that works. throw e however still produces null

Comment: Does it work if you add `throws UnknownHostException` to the method header with the first code?

Comment: question : if you're going to just throw it, why catch it in the first place ?

Comment: Well I didn't add some logging I did etc. Theres are some more lines of code

Comment: Hmm, does it throw NPE when you do `e.printStackTrace()` ? Try cleaning and then rebuilding it, and report to us. `e` just can't be null on that line, and to me, that suggests that your debugger/code is out of sync somehow.

Comment: Are you sure your debugger is displaying what you expect it to? - What happens when you just run your code? NPE? Or does it work then?

Comment: After debugging more it seems like a compiler bug. I am pretty sure it's null  as the runtime is then throwing a null pointer exception as I try to StackTrace() it...so the dbg'r is not lying.

Comment: What a strange bug! I looked up the comments, correct me if I'm wrong, does it works if you add `throws UnknownHostException`? Why don't just keep it? Or better, why not add `throws IOException` because that's precisely what it throws.

Comment: Well, I thought that you necessarily had to add `throws` clause

Comment: try using a different variable name for the Exception.

Comment: If you throw Exception() instead of rethrowing e or e wrapped in an exception does whatever layer further up behave the same?

Comment: If it compiles with `e` as variable name properly, this would not help at all!

Answer (score 1):

I don't even see the point of catching the exception if you just immediately rethrow it.  Add a `throws IOException` to that method and let the other `catch` handle it.

Comment: While your argument is generally valid, in this case it does not help: the OP already explained this, he has other instructions in the catch block too, like logging, etc.